# How to check changes of a file in last commit done in openshift

Tags: git, openshift

I have done commits and pushed the code using git in openshift Application.

Now I need to check my changes in 1 file what I have done in my last commit. How can I do that?

Comment: this is a git question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
git show HEAD path/to/example.txt
```

`git show` shows information about some object, `HEAD` refers to the most recent commit on your local current branch, `example.txt` is the file you want to view the diff for, and `path/to` is the path to that file from the repository root.

Answer (score 2):

`git diff HEAD HEAD^ myfile.txt` will show you what changed in myfile.txt in your last commit.